# Get the nth item of JSON array in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

Using MongoDb how do you get back the date, and 3rd "obs" back from below?

```
 {   "data" : [
          {  "val" : [
                    {  "obs" : "2/3/2016"
                    }, 
                    {  "obs" : 41.8599992990494
                    }, 
                    {  "obs" : 41.3111999630928
                    }, 
                    {  "obs" : 5.048
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {  "val" : [
                    {  "obs" : "2/4/2016"
                    },                
                    {  "obs" : 39.394998550415
                    }, 
                    {  "obs" : 41.8486998975277
                    }, 
                    {  "obs" : NumberInt(0)
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            { "val" : [
                    {  "obs" : "2/5/2016"
                    }, 
                    {  "obs" : NumberInt(0)
                    }, 
                    {  "obs" : 40.2090013027191
                    }, 
                    {  "obs" : 24.2410004138947
                    }, 
                    {  "obs" : 3.629
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]   
    }
```

Started with this:

```
 db.myColl.find({},{"_id":0, "data.val.obs": 1, })
```

would like:

```
["2/3/2016", 41.3111], ["2/4/2016", 41.8486]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do this in MongoDB starting from v 3.4

```js
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
 {
  $addFields: {
   data: {
    $map: {
     input: "$data",
     as: "item",
     in: {$concatArrays: [{$slice: ['$$item.val', 1]}, {$slice: ['$$item.val', 2, 1]}]}
    }
   }
  }
 }
]);
```

So basically I'm using $addFields not to lose other properties of a root document (as you might need them). If you don't need them you can switch to $project.

Example: collection records look like this: `{_id: ..., data: [...], data_2: [...]}`.
If you run the query as is you'll have 'data' array filtered. But you'll still have data_2 unchanged. If you replace $addFields with $project you'll lose data_2. (or you need to explicitly tell mongo to keep it by passing data_2: true)

Then I'm mapping each element of 'data' array and assign the result back to 'data' array so in fact data property is overridden by filtered array.

To get 1st and 3rd elements I use $slice (each $slice returns an array of one document). And then I join them into a single array by $concatArrays.

Comment: What about using $unwind?? Can you include answer with $project

Comment: @Merlin Not sure we need to use $unwind here. We could unwind 'data' to get filtered val objects of different records mixed together for example. But I don't see a particular reason to do this. Regarding the $project, I'll add this tomorrow morning. Basically if the document has not only data property but also e.g. data_2 array, then $addFields keeps it untouched. Same with other properties if any. If you replace $addFields with $project you would have to manually specify which props you would like to keep.